# awk giving different behavior on different systems

Tags: bash, awk

I am using awk to grep a paragraph containing a specific keyword until the record seperator which in my case is the space.

```
awk -vRS= /\<keyword2\>/ file.txt
```

and file.txt contains this

```
this is the first keyword1 occurance
and line in the first paragraph

this is the second keyword2 occurance
and line in the second paragraph
```

now the output of the `awk` command should be

```
this is the second keyword2 occurance
and line in the second paragraph
```

but it works only on one of my system. doesn't work on the others. please help

**Error found**
Installed `nawk` on Ubuntu 14.04 and does not work.
Works fine with `gawk`

Comment: what means not work in other system? which system is yours and which other?

Comment: on some ubuntu systems

Comment: i guess its due to some exact word matching behavior that i want

Comment: It seem that there was a post that adding single quote did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\<keyword2\>/,/^$/p' file.txt
```

Comment: nah, it doesn't work this way. doesn't find anything

Comment: its probably related to the word boundry. if i remove the word boundry checking then it works but i want the exact word matching!

Comment: @dreamer, awk works for me so can't help with that but you can try the sed command above

Comment: @dreamer This will fail if there are more lines in the paragraph and `keyword2` is not on the first line.  You are asking for a keyword in the paragraph, not telling where it is. It will then miss the line above in the keyword in the paragraph. (see example in my post).

Comment: @Jotne well i didn't check the above `sed code` to see if it works with paragrapshs where keyword falls in middle of the para. my requirement was very specific and the keyword will always be the start of paragraph for me. :)

Comment: @dreamer Then update your post with that keyword are always in first line.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close with your `awk`

```
cat file
More data
this is the first keyword1 occurance
and line in the first paragraph

Another data
this is the second keyword2 occurance
and line in the second paragraph
```

```
awk -v RS= '/\<keyword2\>/' file
Another data
this is the second keyword2 occurance
and line in the second paragraph
```

You can also try to skip to word boundary:

```
awk -v RS= '/keyword2/' file
```

---

A `perl` version:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/="\n\n" }; print if $_ =~ /keyword2/;' file
```

---

`sed` version

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/\<keyword2\>/!d;' file

Another data
this is the second keyword2 occurance
and line in the second paragraph
```

or

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/keyword2/!d;' file
```

Comment: @perreal It does contain singe quote `'`

Comment: look at the previous version of my answer if you are really bored. OP says single quotes won't help.

Comment: @perreal That should not be removed, since its important for new user also to get this info.  It may help to remove the word boundary. I update original post. You could also try to modify `sed` to get the complete paragraph.

Comment: @dreamer What does not work? I tried it on 4 different system with the  data posted in first post all ok.  Do you have other data? What is your system?

Comment: i hv the standard Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation.

Comment: @dreamer It works fine on my Ubuntu 14.04, then your data needs to be different than what you post here.

Comment: nah, its the same. :)

Comment: actually on my system, mawk is installed, and the systems where it works correctly have gawk installed.

Comment: @dreamer Then on the Ubuntu version try to run `gawk`.  And do you get `mawk` or `gawk `if you type `awk -v` (look at the last line)

Comment: then it works, but because gawk doesn't come by default on standard installation, i don't want to use it.

Comment: `gawk` has been standard as long as I have used Ubuntu. LOOOONG time

Comment: then why didn't it come on mine? i downloaded it from ubuntu official website :)

Comment: I do not know, on my Ubuntu Server 14.04 I do have it?  And if you do not have it, I do suggest you install `gawk`

Comment: Taken from some other forum `GAWK stands for “GNU AWK”. All Linux distributions comes with GAWK. This is fully compatible with AWK and NAWK.`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use [GNU awk extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) on an incompatible implementation of awk.

Unfortunately there is no POSIX-standard word boundary marker. Depending on exactly what the text is, you might be able to use:

```
awk -vRS= '/[[:space:]]keyword2[[:space:]]/' file.txt
```

Which will match keyword2 with spaces either side. This should work on any implementation of awk.